# Detect keyboard input and mouse activity on a single form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this below form and I want to detect key-strokes and any mouse clicks on the button.

For example, if I press <kbd>S</kbd> on my keyboard, **message** will show **START** and **keypress** will display **keyboard press**. The same thing happen when mouse-click on **START** button, except that **keypress** will display **START BTN**.

[image]

Here is my button code. If I only do for button or only `IsKeyDown` it works fine, but when I combine both in one form, they go haywire.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblKeypress.Text = "START BTN";
    lblmessage.Text = "START";
}
```

Here is my `Keyboard.IsKeyDown` code:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.S))
    {
        lblKeypress.Text = "Keyboard Press";
        lblmessage.Text = "START";
    }
}
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: what do you mean "when I combine both in one form, they go haywire"

Comment: no error shown up, but when both code applied in same windows form, only button can be clicked, and nothing happen when I pressed S on my keyboard. its like only one  is enabled. could it be that way? I can't use both at the same time? I think it not supposed to be, right?

Comment: @s.young, I've updated the answer below, let me know if that works

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your *Form* you set `KeyPreviewProperty` to **TRUE**

In *Form1.Designer.cs*

`this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.form_keydown);`

```
private void form_keydown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
       int keyVal = (int)e.KeyValue;
       keyValue = -1;

      if ((keyVal >= (int)Keys.S))
      {
          keyValue = (int)e.KeyValue - (int)Keys.S;
          lblKeypress.Text = "Keyboard Press";
          lblmessage.Text = "START";
       }

 }
```

*Note:*

- *Ensure you do not have any unrelated WPF namespaces`*
- `(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.S))` is a `WPF` approach, in WinForms you are better off using combination of `e.KeyValue & Keys`

Comment: Please remember that a common mistake is that the user forgets to add the event handler when copying in code. To make this method work, just add the following in the constructor of your form `this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(form_keydown);` or add it through the IDE's forms editor.

Comment: Although it is not wrong, it is however important to also note that unless you really know what you are doing, you shouldn't be messing around in form.Designer.cs, this is why I mentioned putting the aforementioned line of code in the forms constructor method in form.cs as this does not have a chance to mess up any of the other code in the Designer.cs.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, 
 EventArgs e){
   if (e.KeyData == Keys.S){
      lblKeypress.Text = "Keyboard Press";
      lblmessage.Text = "START";
    }
}
```